# Session expiry in Django in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

I'm using Django version 1.8. I need to kill the sessions when the browser is closed. I have set the following property in settings.py:

> SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

However, as this [note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) in the documentation says, it doesn't work in Chrome browser. So, What is the solution for session expiry while using Chrome?

Comment: Doesn't look like this has any resolution as this is not a bug in Django, just a special feature that chrome provides. On Chrome this can only be handled by changing the settings I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome will be actually still running in background that may need that session data, you need to close all background tasks to really close the browser and delete the django_session.

Unfortunately, there is no programmatic way of deleting session data in Google Chrome when browser closes.